# How to assign grid span in airbnb Epoxy?

Tags: android, epoxy, epoxy-modelview

I've been starting learning how to use Epoxy in my project. I'm learning this library by running [sample project](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/tree/master/epoxy-sample). Everything was fine until I dig into the grid span settings. I found myself confused about its grid system.

[image]

As you can see in sample app the ViewHolders can be divided in 3 parts. Those parts can be represented particularly in models, such as `HeaderViewModel_`, `ButtonBindingModel_` and `CarouselModelGroup`.

And the code of init RecyclerView is the following:

```
EpoxyRecyclerView recyclerView = (EpoxyRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
```

According to offical doc:

> If a GridLayoutManager is used this will automatically sync the span
>   count with the EpoxyController.

I found `HeaderViewModel_` and `CarouselModelGroup` is correctly sync the span, but `ButtonBindingModel_` is not. I've been searching the word "span" or "grid" over the sample codes, **I just couldn't figure out why `ButtonBindingModel_` could have its span to be set as 1.**

If I change the span setting of RecyclerView from 2 to 3:

```
EpoxyRecyclerView recyclerView = (EpoxyRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
```

[image]

`HeaderViewModel_` and `CarouselModelGroup` still remained to sync the full span, but the span of `ButtonBindingModel_` is still 1.

I would like to know if there is an approach to make the span of `ButtonBindingModel_` to full span, and method to set `HeaderViewModel_` and `CarouselModelGroup` to specific span no matter by code (programmatically) or by layout. Please help me to figure out this problem, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing we used was setting the span on a model basis using `spanSizeOverride`.
We've got a few different models that we want at 2 vs 1 for the span so we set that override on them.

```
gridLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = ourController.spanSizeLookup
...

collectionDescription {
  id(DESCRIPTION_ID)
  description(data.description ?: "")
  spanSizeOverride { _, _, _ -> 2 }
}
data.productTemplates?.forEachIndexed { index, product ->
  collectionProduct {
    id("$PRODUCT_ID ${product.slug} $index")
    product(product)
    listener(listener)
  }
}
```